# Errors when build unity proejct for Macos on Windows

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I want to build a macOS version of my Unity project, I get following errors. But When I choose to Build Winows Version, it goes very well. Can someone help with this problem?

Many Thanks.

My version of Unity package is 2020.3.18f1c1 and my computer is Windows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex7Wb.png)

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\UI\Core\Image.cs(873,87): error CS1061: 'Sprite' does not contain a definition for 'isUsingPlaceholder' and no accessible extension method 'isUsingPlaceholder' accepting a first argument of type 'Sprite' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\UI\Core\Image.cs(1851,38): error CS1061: 'SpriteAtlas' does not contain a definition for 'IsPlaceholder' and no accessible extension method 'IsPlaceholder' accepting a first argument of type 'SpriteAtlas' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: In general I think this can't be done ... afaik in order to build for Mac/iOS you need to be on Mac

Comment: Hmm, but my friends are also on windows, and they can build for macOS simply by installing the MacOS support module. I got the errors in the image after I installed the macOS support, but thank for replying me anyway

Answer (score 0):

It would work fine after upgrading your unity engine to 2021.3 in your situation